# Insert characters within a link - targeting specific levels

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a list that is generated by Wordpress (so I can't change it):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
   <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
         <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>   
         </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

I then have some jquery that is putting bullets and dashes within specific levels:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('ul.children li a').prepend('&#8226; ');
    $('ul.children li ul.children a').prepend('&#45; ');        
});
});
</script>
```

**It puts the bullets in fine on the level 2 links and the dashes go in fine on level 3. How can I say that I don't want the dashes to be added to the level 3 links as well... which is what it currently does!**

At the moment it displays - • Level 3, I only want it to show - Level 3 Page

Comment: `… li a` will select _all_ `a` elements underneath the `li`, no matter on what level (all “descendants”) – if you only want to select those that are direct child elements, use the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#child-combinators) – see also http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: @CBroe Got very close with this - I tried `$('ul.children>li a').prepend('&#8226; ');$('ul.children li>ul.children a').prepend('&#45; ');` but not quite right.

Comment: `ul.children > li > a` will target only the second level links, and `ul.children > li > ul.children > li > a` will target those on second level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $('ul.children').has('ul').children('li').children('a').prepend('&#8226; '); //Bullets on level 2
   $('ul.children ul.children').children('li').children('a').prepend('&#45; '); //Dashes on level 3
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> list that is generated by Wordpress (so I can't change it)

The fact that this list is generated by Wordpress doesn't mean you can't change it.
This way of "thinking" is causing a really bad practice , using `javascript` / `jquery` just to add a "visual" element to the document is a bad practice indeed.

Anyway , even if you don't want to change the HTML , why not using `css` which its
whole purpose is `styling` the document?

**UPDATE**
I don't understand why the downvote,
anyway , here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate my answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/hWfNy/1/

Code:

```
ul.children li a:before { content: '\2022\00a0 '}
ul.children > ul.children li a:before{ content: '\2D\00a0 ' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parent of the list as reference:

```
.parent > ul > li > ul > li > a::before{
  content: '•';
}

.parent > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a::before{
  content: '-';
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FYf5/)** *(note: I corrected the original markup from the Q, WP doesn't generate invalid markup)*

The same applies for the jQuery solution, but without the `::after` pseudo-selector. It's also possible without using the parent, but I think it makes the code less readable:

```
ul:not(.children) > li > ul > li > a::before { ... } 
ul:not(.children) > li > ul > li > ul > li > a::before { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

My own approach would be somewhat different (and hopefully more extensible should you want to apply different markers later on):

```
// defining the markers to apply to each 'level':
var levelPrefixMap = {
    '1': '',
    '2': '• ',
    '3': '- '
};

// selecting all the 'a' elements, iterating over them:
$('a').each(function () {
    // we're using '$(this)' a few times, caching to save time
    var self = $(this),
        // gets the number of parents as a proxy for the 'depth'/'level':
        level = self.parents('ul').length;
    // changing the text of the current 'a' element:
    self.text(function(i,t){
        /* if we have a marker set for this 'level', we return that and the text,
           otherwise we just return the text:
        */
        return levelPrefixMap.hasOwnProperty(level) ? levelPrefixMap[level] + t : t;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uBaZH/).

References:

- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`Object.hasOWnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).